# bash: Stop escaping quotes when passing variables to command

Tags: bash

I have a bash-script that constructs arguments that should be passed to another function.

The function to call looks like this:

```
./someCommand -H 'key1: val1' -H 'key2: val2' -H 'key3: val3'
```

Within my bash script, I construct the variable "HEADER_STR" as such:

```
HEADER_STR=""
HEADER_STR="$HEADER_STR -H '$keypair2'"
HEADER_STR="$HEADER_STR -H '$keypair3'"
```

(The actual logic is more complicated and involves argument parsing. But the concept is the same. The number of key-pairs is arbitrary.)

As a result `echo "HEADER: ${HEADER_STR}"` prints `HEADER:  -H 'key2: val2' -H 'key3: val3'`

Now I want to pass this to another script as-is:

```
set -o xtrace  # to print the command before it gets executed
./someCommand -H 'key1: val1' ${HEADER_STR}
```

This does not work. For some reason, the single-ticks within my HEADER_STR get escaped and result in `'\''`.
This is what gets printed/executed instead:

```
./someCommand -H 'key1: val1' -H ''\''key2: key2'\''' -H ''\''key3: key3'\'''
```

I already tried all kinds of syntax, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Use an array instead. Like `hdrs=(); hdrs+=(-H "$keypair2"); ...; cmd "${hdrs[@]}"`